# Why is my regex removing spaces?

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = "&amp; &svnips &nbsp; &Acirc; &there4; &asymp; osidnviosd & sopinsdo";   
$regex = "/&[^\w;]/";
echo preg_replace($regex, "&amp;", $str);
```

I'm trying to replace all un-encoded ampersands with encoded ones.
The problem is it's removing the space between `&` and `sopinsdo`.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use regex?  Why not use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Note the fourth parameter.  It tells it not to double encode anything.  So basically, this will turn all `<` into `&lt;`, all `>` into `&gt;` and all `&` that are not part of an existing entity into `&amp;`

But, if you must use regex, you could do:

```
$regex = '/&([^\w;])/';
echo preg_replace($regex, '&amp;\1', $str);
```

Basically, it saves the non-word character and then adds it back...

Answer (score 2):

You search for 2 Characters ("&" and a character that is NOT (; or \w))and replace it with `&amp;`

You should replace with `&amp;` (add a space to the end of replace string)

Comment: This has the same issue as unigg's answer below. There are cases where this will cause undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This regex does what you're looking for.

```
preg_replace('/&(?!\w+;)/', '&amp;', $text);
```

So for a few simple test cases you can get properly escaped HTML:

```
'& sopinsdo'          -> '&amp; sopinsdo'
'&amp; sopinsdo'      -> '&amp; sopinsdo'
'sopinsdo & foo; bar' -> 'sopinsdo &amp; foo; bar'
'sopinsdo &foo bar'   -> 'sopinsdo &amp;foo bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want the space between **&** and **sopinsdo** removed. Just add one

```
echo preg_replace($regex, "&amp; ", $str);
```